# Manipulating DOM in Vue 2.2.1 using Tether is causing errors. Is there a right way to do it?

Tags: dom, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tether

I'm trying to use [`tether`](http://tether.io/) and `vue 2.2.1` together. Here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/awei01/fwttsa6o/2/

What (i think) `tether` does:

- If the tethered DOM node is inside the normal document flow (not `position: absolute`), the `tether` code will simply add some style attributes to position the tethered element correctly
- If the tethered DOM node has `position: absolute`, `tether` will move the tethered DOM node and place it as a child of `body`. This is causing problems for `vue`. Specifically, an exception is thrown: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

I've tried to solve this issue by fiddling with the `beforeDestroy`, `destroyed` lifecycle hooks of the `Popup` component, but it doesn't seem to help.

I was able to solve this issue in `react` by simply moving the tethered DOM element back to its original position on `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook.

I'm wondering what is the best way to solve this issue in `vue`. Another thought I had was to preemptively insert a new DOM node to `body` and force the `Popup` component to use that node to render, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use v-show instead of v-if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from `v-if` to `v-show` seems to fix the issue.

```
<popup v-show="popup1" target="anchor1">
    Some popup content
</popup>
```